# How to send params from nested forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, reactjs

I'm making a `POST` request from a `nested form` which is written in `reactjs` such that it is making an `ajax` request to `create` method of the `products controller`.

**React Code:**

I have an empty object in the `getInitialState` like this

```
getInitialState: function() {
 return {
   products: [{name: '', price: '', quantity: ''}],
   count: 1
 };
},
```

When i submit the form,

```
handleSubmit: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var productsArray = this.state.products;
  $.ajax({
    data: {
      product: productsArray
    },
    url: '',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function ( data ) {
      console.log(data);
      // this.setState({ comments: data });
    }.bind(this)
  });
},
```

the object gets populated and the `parameter` hash becomes like this

```
Parameters: {"product"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"", "price"=>"", "quantity"=>""}}, "shop_id"=>"gulshop"}
```

So i'm getting

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute '0' for Product.):
```

How can i get the `parameter` hash like this:

```
Parameters: {"product"=>[{"name"=>"", "price"=>"", "quantity"=>""}], "shop_id"=>"gulshop"}
```

What can be done for it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your original error 'unknown attribute '0' for Product.' is because the Product class does not have an attribute '0'. I'm not sure where the '0' is coming from as you haven't posted your react code that makes the request.

You can easily make a request from your component using jQuery's .ajax method. e.g

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/your_url',
  data: {
    course: {
      name: 'Hello World',
      price: 120
    }
  }
});
```

You would then have something like the following in your controller..

```
class ProductController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @product = Product.create(product_params)
  end

  private

  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name, :price)
  end
end
```